# Building software in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm spoiled because I learned to write software on OSX and Linux where the tooling is straightforward and IDEs typically just use an external build system to do all of the heavy lifting.  I recently tried VS2015 and I have to say the code editor is really good and the UI isn't bad.  I wouldn't say I like the interface as much as qtcreator but the debugging support looks pretty good.

Anyway, I'm working on a game and want to try using Visual Studio (and only visual studio - I'm aware of CMake and premake) to build my project.  The problem is that it's not a terribly simple project to build - at least not in Visual Studio.

It's written in standard C, no surprises there.  I have a library (`common.lib`) and its client application (`mygame.exe`).  `common.lib` and `mygame.exe` use functionality from `libpng`, `GLEW`, `SDL2`, and `freetype`, so I am having problems with two things: include paths and linker paths.  I can manually specify these in my project settings, but what if I want to give the project to someone else to work on?  My libraries are installed in `C:/OSS` but his may not be.

With 30 lines of autotools I could use `pkg-config` to find the right include paths and linker paths and link the right libraries in, but It's a real hassle to use that on windows.  What is the standard way of configuring dependencies in Visual Studio?  Also, what is the best way to tell Visual Studio that `mygame.exe` needs to be linked with `common.lib`?

Later in the development process, will it be feasible to use Visual Studio to run custom build steps to say, embed GLSL shaders into my application?

Comment: You can use relative paths for your external dependencies.  Chances are you're going to want to be building/linking a specific version of the externals so you don't have issues when the API changes.

Comment: @Retired Ninga: Is it customary to just include said library in your project in source form?  How is this done with projects that are complicated to build like SDL?

Comment: It depends.  If you need to debug and step into the library you're probably going to want to build from source, otherwise the binary is probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

For defining link dependencies, there are three ways:

- The standard way of defining 'external' link dependencies in Visual Studio is to input them in your project properties. If you are developing a C project, this would be in the `Project->Properties... Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` property. To configure the directory that the libraries are in, that is done in `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`. Generally, you make the directories relative to your project, so you can relocate your project, or have it work for other users getting it from source control with a different workspace mapping.
- If you are compiling static libraries within the same solution file, adding a dependency between your executable/dll and the static library will cause the static library to be linked (by default) into the executable, so you do not have to modify any settings. This can be done from `Project->Project Dependencies...`.
- You can also use statements to link libraries, for example: `#pragma comment(lib, "library.lib")` within the source code itself, which would cause the linker to try and link with "library.lib". However, I wouldn't recommend it, as it can obfuscate the linking process.

As for embedding GLSL shaders, you can just embed them as strings in a .c/.cpp file, and have that source file compiled, so it's not a very good example for embedding resources. But, to answer generally, you can embed resources within an application, by creating a resource file, and then importing any file you wish. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy.aspx) for more information. You can then access them with [FindResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx) and [LoadResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you're looking to somehow precompile your shaders and embed them (as you might do with say DirectX HLSL), you can make custom build commands to do this. In the `Project->Properties...Custom Build Step` - generally this is used on a per-file basis. You can also create custom build rules, for files of a particular type (eg. *`.glsl`). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy.aspx) for more information on how to do that.

Also, lots of people like to hate on Visual Studio. It does have a learning curve, just like every other reasonably functional IDE. If you don't like it, don't use it. As you said, you have plenty of other options, even on Windows.